# appending a tkinter text widget with google search results

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, google-search

Good morning,
Right now I'm struggling with a small program, that lets you search google within a tkinter GUI. After you press the button it should show all the links(for me I limited it to 10) for that result.
My program works but it doesn't append the text box but just shows the last result of the query.
The important part of my code starts in the def clicked().

```
import tkinter
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import cv2
from googlesearch import search

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title("Google Search")
window.geometry('1000x1000')

img = "pics1/dt.jpg"
img2 = "pics2/donald.jpg"
cv_img = cv2.imread(img)
cv_img2 = cv2.imread(img2)
height, width, no_channels = cv_img.shape
height, width, no_channels = cv_img2.shape
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=2)
photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv_img))
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=tkinter.NW)

######


txt = tkinter.Entry(window,width=10)
txt.grid(column=0, row=1)
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Who do you want to search?")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)


canvas2 = tkinter.Canvas(window, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas2.grid(row=0, column=1)
photo2 = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv_img2))
canvas2.create_image(0, 0, image=photo2, anchor=tkinter.NW)

query = ""

def clicked():
    res = "Thanks"
    global query
    query = txt.get()
    lbl.configure(text=res)

    for j in search(query, tld='com', lang='en', num=10, start=0, stop=10, pause=2):
        final = tkinter.Text(window, text=j)

btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Search", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=0, row=3)





window.mainloop()
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Are you intentionally wanting to create a new text widget for every single result, or is it your desire to put all of the results in a single window?

Comment: Read about [Text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) and how to insert multiple lines of text.

Comment: @BryanOakley I would like to put all of them into a single text widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the creation of the text widget from the function, and instead create it in the main part of your script. Then, call the `insert` method to insert into the text widget.

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
...
text = tkinter.Text(window)
# this is just guessing where you want it; put
# it wherever you want. 
text.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)
...

def clicked():
    ...
    for j in search(query, tld='com', lang='en', num=10, start=0, stop=10, pause=2):
        text.insert("end", j)
```

If the results don't end in a newline, you will need to add one. For example:

```
text.insert("end", j+"\n")
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you so much for helping a bloody beginner ;-D